# Building monotools-server, gtk+, pango - bizarre path issues

Tags: configuration, mono, make, gtk

I'm attempting to build the monotools-server app from source. After **days** of hunting down missing dependencies (and in one case (`xsp`) having to manually modify a generated `Makefile` to remove a reference to a test project which requires a missing `Mono.Data.SqliteClient.dll`, a bug which was reported over a year ago), I'm down to gtk+-2.24.

When I run the ./configure script for gtk+, I see yet more missing packages:

```
configure: error: Package requirements (glib-2.0 >= 2.27.3    atk >= 1.29.2    pango >= 1.20    cairo >= 1.6    gdk-pixbuf-2.0 >= 2.21.0) were not met:

No package 'atk' found
No package 'pango' found
No package 'cairo' found
No package 'gdk-pixbuf-2.0' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.
```

Okay, fine, so I download pango 1.28.4. The `configure` script

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME
```

runs just fine, and creates a whole mess of make files and .pc's.

When I run `make`, I get the error:

```
[slively@gpu1 pango-1.28.4]$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory `/lustre/users/slively/download/pango-1.28.4'
Making all in pango
make[2]: Entering directory `/lustre/users/slively/download/pango-1.28.4/pango'
  GEN    s-enum-types-h
/bin/sh: line 1: ..//users/slively/lib/pkgconfig/./gobject/glib-mkenums: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [s-enum-types-h] Error 127
make[2]: Leaving directory `/lustre/users/slively/download/pango-1.28.4/pango'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/lustre/users/slively/download/pango-1.28.4'
make: *** [all] Error 2
[slively@gpu1 pango-1.28.4]$
```

A few things jump out at me:

First, the error:

```
bin/sh: line 1: ..//users/slively/lib/pkgconfig/./gobject/glib-mkenums: No such file or directory
```

What's up with that path?! `..//users/slively/lib/pkgconfig/./gobject/glib-mkenums`? Aside from the weird `..//` at the start of the path (it should be `/users/slively/...`, I searched my home directory for `gobject` and found:

```
[slively@gpu1 ~]$ find . -name gobject*
./bin/gobject-query
./include/glib-2.0/gobject
./include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobject.h
./include/glib-2.0/gobject/gobjectnotifyqueue.c
./share/man/man1/gobject-query.1
./share/glib-2.0/gdb/gobject.py
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Boxed-Types.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Closures.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject.devhelp
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject.devhelp2
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Enumeration-and-Flag-Types.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Generic-values.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-GParamSpec.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-memory.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-properties.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-query.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Signals.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Standard-Parameter-and-Value-Types.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-The-Base-Object-Type.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Type-Information.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Value-arrays.html
./share/gtk-doc/html/gobject/gobject-Varargs-Value-Collection.html
./lib/pkgconfig/gobject-2.0.pc
./lib/pkgconfig/gobject-2.0-uninstalled.pc
[slively@gpu1 ~]$
```

And, the only instances of `glib-mkenums` are in `~/bin` and the donwload folder where I built glib.

```
[slively@gpu1 ~]$ find . -name glib-mkenums
./bin/glib-mkenums
./download/glib-2.28.6/gobject/glib-mkenums
[slively@gpu1 ~]$
```

What am I missing here? One thing I love about Windows: install = "click click, Accept."

HELP.

Comment: On what OS (if Linux, what distribution), and what architecture? Why aren't you installing binary packages (at least the gtk stuff should be a `yum install`/`apt-get install`/`pkg_add`/… away)?

Comment: This is on Scientific Linux SL 5.5 (Boron), which seems to be derived from red hat. I don't have root access to the machine - just trying to get these items built in my home directory.

Comment: @David: I recommend getting the source RPMs and building them with a different installation directory (I think it's easy with rpm, but I don't remember how).

Comment: Is the content of the RPM somehow different from the source tar ball?

Comment: @David: It might have patches that were needed on your distribution, and more likely and more importantly it will have a full compilation script.

Comment: @Gilles thanks. The latest RPM I can find is 1.20.1. I'll give it a shot. (If you want to copy your comments into an answer I'll happily upvote.)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the RPM has the same contents as the tarball I already had. =/ I don't understand why anyone would bother distributing a version of their package that won't even compile. =[

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something, no one maintains packages specifically for Scientific Linux. I'd love to know if there is another distribution that has compatible binaries. It'd probably save me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @David: Since SL is derived from Red Hat, Red Hat (or CentOS) packages might work. But not being root does make things less convenient. Most Linux software can in fact be compiled with just `./configure --prefix=$HOME && make && make install`, though you have to track dependencies (Gnome stuff has a lot). I don't know what's going wrong with your compilation (obviously a broken makefile or script, but where?).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similiar problem and after a long time of looking, I stumbled uppon the solutions which is very simple. I deleted all *uninstalled.pc files from my local pkgconfig directory. Hope it works for you too.